# Problems importing Illustrator files into Flash

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Illustrator files don't always import correctly into Flash. What are the common reasons for failure and is there any way to improve the import quality?

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator supports many advanced graphics features that Flash does not. Certain shapes are converted to bitmaps, and certain shapes don't import properly at all. Some of them are:

- **Mesh gradients** - Flash only supports linear/radial gradients, so if you want to preserve these, you'll have to import these as bitmaps
- **Opacity masks** - Flash only supports fully opaque masks, not alpha masks. May not import properly no matter what settings you use. Will need touch-up work post-import.

The things that easily import 1:1 are:

- **Shapes** - Imports perfectly
- **Solid fills/strokes** - Imports perfectly
- **Linear & Radial gradients** - Imports perfectly
- **Text** - Can be problematic but mostly perfect - Imports perfectly